# plugin development in xt:commerece

Tags: php, plugins

I have installed [xt:commerece](http://www.xt-commerce.co.uk/) a shoping cart related site. I want to develop a plugin within this CMS. But the documentation that they give in their admin panel is quite minimul. Is there any body who has already done this job can tell me where to find its documentation?

1. Or can tell me what are hooks here?
2. Where to find functions?
3. How to find keys for code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only documentation I found 
http://webhelp-de.xt-commerce.com/HTML_EN/index.html?xt_serials.htm

look under Developer Information -> Pluginsystem
Note it is also very brief and not very clear.

Have you managed to find any other documentation for this? That would be helpful as I am facing the same problem.

EDIT: Documentation moved to https://xtcommerce.atlassian.net/wiki/display/MANUAL/Entwicklerinformationen

Comment: I have developed. Put your problem, I will try to answer that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to XT-Commerce documentation I found.
https://xtcommerce.atlassian.net/wiki/display/MANUAL/Entwicklerinformationen.
Hooks are also mentioned there.